# custom clock widget not work in android 4.1.2

Tags: android, android-widget

I got a custom analog clock widget sample in the following link.
https://github.com/xxv/24hAnalogWidget

It work in all android version except android4.1.2 .

It does not show any error, so I cannot find what problems with this.
Can anyone tell me what's the problems?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find any problem with the Custom Widget you provide .I Tested it with both device and Emulator

If you wan try something different [See This](https://github.com/RonzyFonzy/ClockWidget)